# Xcode hidesBarOnSwipe = false does not work with table view controller

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a xcode project that lists some official datas. My problem is about navigation bar. As you know, on screens that contain TableView, when you scroll the screen, navigation bar automatically hides. But I want to change the behavior. I want to make navigationBar always appear on top. Even though I added following codes, it still hides on swipe. How can I fix the problem.

```
self.navigationController?.hidesBarOnSwipe = false
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
```

NOT: My screen is embedded in a navigationController.

Comment: Navigation bars do *not* automatically hide on swipe unless `hidesBarOnSwipe` is `true` (and it defaults to `false`). A large title will collapse to a small title when scrolling, and since iOS 15 the default appearance for a navigation bar is to be transparent when there is no content behind it. But the bar does not hide - it is still there with any bar buttons and a title visible.